# Does a program's call stack differ depending on OS and/or programming language?

Tags: operating-system, stack, programming-languages

I understand that the call stack has a well defined way of operating in linux IA32. The way in which the call stack is operated may change from architecture to another. But is it also dependent on the programming language and operating system?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Comment: Upvoted, because the question makes sense, although it is likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred CPU-level call stack depends on the architecture. Historically, CPUs have had instructions supporting stacks that grow to either lower or higher memory addresses, and the contents of the stacks have varied with the architecture, and the programming language.

A programming language that is compiled to machine code will likely use the CPU-supported call stack. But any given programming language may choose which stack to use, how to use it, what to place there, and even which context is responsible for popping from the stack (a ["calling convention"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)).

The Wikipedia article for ["Call Stack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) explains what most call stacks contain, and how they are used.

Operating systems will adapt to the CPU architecture *through* the programming language in which they are written (`C`is common, but there have been others). OS parts written in assembly will likely use the architecture's conventions.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the call stack can differ from language to language. For example, some languages push parameters in left-to-right order, and others in right-to-left order. Some depend on the caller to clean up the stack on return, and others depend on the callee to do it.

Consider, for example, the different [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).